# Cauchy’s Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the question:
Show that $$ =\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{-2i}{(3z^{2}+10z+3)} dz\ = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

I’ve put what I’ve done in the answer but I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong as I can’t get the answer it’s given!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was when applying Cauchy's Integral formula.

\begin{equation}
\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{f(z)}{(3z+1)} \text{d}z = \frac{1}{3}\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{f(z)}{z - \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)} \text{d}z = \frac{2}{3} \pi i f\left( -\frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{2}{3} \pi i \cdot \left(-\frac{2 i}{8/3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$\oint \frac {-2i}{3z^2 + 10z + 3}\ dz\\
\oint \frac {-2i}{(3z + 1)(z + 3)}\ dz$

Only one of these poles is inside the contour.  At this point you could use partial fractions, or calculate the residues.  Since you metion Cauchy's integral formula, lets use that.

$\oint \frac {f(z)}{z-a}\ dz = 2\pi i f(a)$

Let $f(z) = \frac {-2i}{3(z+3)}$

$\oint \frac {f(z)}{z+\frac 13}\ dz = 2\pi i f(-\frac 13) = 2\pi i \left(\frac {-2i}{3(\frac{8}{3})}\right)= \frac {\pi}{2}$